# How to pass objects to functions by reference in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile my code by using make file. It seems to me that I have a bit problem in my code but it gave me no error except reference problem( referenced from:_main in lab2-f679eb.o )

I am trying to pass the object to function by reference.

This is my general code:
In main.cpp:

```
ClassName obj
obj.functionName(obj); // passing object to the funcion
```

In other.cpp

```
 FunctionName(ClassName &obj){
 cout<<"Please enter first name:"<<endl;
 cin>>user.fname;
 cout<<"Please enter last name:"<<endl;
 cin>>user.lname;
 }
```

In header.h:

```
  Class ClassName
  {
    public:
         std::string fname;
         std::string lname;
         FunctionName(ClassName& obj);
  };
```

The big question is that, do I have a correct structure or not ? what I want to do to pass the object to function not method. When I run the code there is no error but it gave me

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"ClassName:: FunctionName(ClassName&)", referenced from:
 _main in lab2-f679eb.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Please post your actual code, `Function(&B)` is not valid C++. Also you're declaring `Function` but calling `function`. C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: int main()
    {
     User user;
     user.Create(user);  //// passing object to the funcion
    }

Comment: This in another cpp void Create(User& user)
{
 cout<<"Enter your Name"<<endl;
}

Comment: This is in the header file: class User
{
 public:
  void Update(User&);

Comment: maybe you meant `Create(user);` instead of `user.Create(user);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a linker error, which means that the compiler was able to compile the program but couldn't find the implementation for one of the member functions you wrote. Notice that it's saying that `ClassA::Function(Class A&)` is the undefined symbol, meaning that the compiler never found an implementation for this function.

So why is that? Well, in `other.cpp`, you implemented the following:

```
ReturnType Function (B&) {
   ...
}
```

This is a *free function* named `Function`, which is not the same as the function `ClassA::Function`. This means that the compiler doesn't treat it as a member function, so when it compiles your code it never ends up finding `ClassA::Function`.

To fix this, change `Function` in the .cpp file so that you explicitly indicate it's a member function:

```
ReturnType ClassA::Function(B&) {
    ...
}
```

That should resolve your error.

Comment: Thanks : I am getting duplicate symbol duplicate symbol _num in:
    lab2.o
    User.o
duplicate symbol _lname in:
    lab2.o
    User.o
duplicate symbol _fname in:
    lab2.o
    User.o
duplicate symbol _name in:
    lab2.o
    User.o
duplicate symbol _age in:
    lab2.o
    User.o
Thanks

Comment: You should post this as a separate question with thee actual code you used and the specific way you were compiling and linking everything. Without seeing more of what you have, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I will answer myself after long tried. I will make my answer in more detailed and more than answer needed.

Here I will write several functions that take different parameter passing( call by value and reference.

Here is my header file.h

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
class User
{


    public:
        std::string fname;
        std::string lname;
        std::string num[5];
        int age;
};

void Update(User &user);
void View(User &user);
void Create(User &user);
void Favorites(User &user);

#endif
```

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;

void 
Create(User& user)
{
    cout<<"Please enter first name:"<<endl;
    cin>>user.fname;
    cout<<"Please enter last name:"<<endl;
    cin>>user.lname;
    cout<<"Please enter age:"<<endl;
    cin>> user.age;
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
}

void 
Update(User& user)
{
    cout<<"Please enter which attribute to update (First, Last, Age):"<<endl;
    string option;
    string Age = "Age", First = "First" , Last = "Last";
    //cout<<"what you want to update"<<endl;
    //cout<<"Please enter which attribute to update (First, Last, Age): "<<endl;
    cin>> option;

        if(option == First)
            {
                cout<<"Please enter the new value:"<<endl;
                cin>>user.fname;
            }

        if(option == Last)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the new value:"<<endl;
            cin>>user.lname;
        }

        if(option == Age)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the new value:"<<endl;
            cin>>user.age;
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n');

        }
}

void 
View(User& user)
{
    cout<<"First name:"<<user.fname<<endl;
    cout<<"Last name:"<< user.lname<<endl;
    cout<<"Age:"<<user.age<<endl;
    cout<<"Favorite Movies"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++)
    {
        cout<<user.num[i]<<endl;
    }
}

void Favorites(User& user)
{
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');

    cout<<"Please input your new 5 Favorite Movies"<<endl;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        //cin>>user.num[i];
        //cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        getline (cin, user.num[i]);
    }
}
```

Finally this is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    User user;
    while(true)
    {
    string option;
    cout<<"Please enter a command (Create, Update, View, Favorites, or Quit):"<<endl;
    cin>> option;
            if(option == "Create")
            {
                Create(user);  //// passing object to the funcion
            }

            else if(option == "Update")
            {
                Update(user);
            }

            else if(option == "View")
            {
                View(user);   //// passing object to the funcion
               // setUserName(User &user, string f, string l);
            }
            else if(option == "Favorites")
            {
                Favorites(user);   //// passing object to the funcion
            }

            else if(option == "Quit")
            {
                cout<<"You Exit from the Program "<<endl;
                break;              
            }
            else if(option != "Create" || option != "Update" || option != "View" || option != "Favorites" || option != "Quit")
                cout<<"INVALID COMMAND"<<endl;              
    }
    return 0;
}
```